# Apply specific margins to first and last element that are not siblings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, margin

I have specific type of boxes in my HTML that have, let's say `margin: 10px;` to all of them. They are displayed in a row on the page (using Bootstrap) and I want to remove the left margin of the first element and the right margin of the last element. I could use `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` and their respective `lasts` but the elements are not siblings and they do not have a common parent. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <div class='MY-CUSTOM-BOX'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class='MY-CUSTOM-BOX'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class='MY-CUSTOM-BOX'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`:first-of-type` applies to all boxes, not sure how to approach the `:first-child` because of the nested `divs`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use a combination of css selectors to achieve this, namely the `>` as well as `:first-child` and `:last-child`

```
:first-child > .MY-CUSTOM-BOX {
  margin-left: 0;
}

:last-child > .MY-CUSTOM-BOX {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This selects the direct `MY-CUSTOM-BOX` descendants of *any* first and last child elements.
That should work where the boxes have the same level of parent (i.e. container -> div -> MY-CUSTOM-BOX)

You could also do it the other way round which may give you better results depending on how nested you are:

```
.container > :first-child .MY-CUSTOM-BOX {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.container > :last-child .MY-CUSTOM-BOX {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This selects the first and last child of `container` and then gives any `MY-CUSTOM-BOX` elements inside it margin left/right of 0.

Here's a (relatively crude) fiddle demonstrating both examples: https://jsfiddle.net/ttakchr1/

Comment: For some reason it works only for the fist but not the last element in both cases. Could it be because there are more <div class='col-md-x'> elements after the last one containing MY-CUSTOM-BOX element?

Comment: The `last-child` selector will find the last element, regardless of it's context so yes, that's exactly the issue.

Comment: At the end of the day this is an answer to the question that works, although it turned out that the problem is a bit more specific. Thank you!